# jquery div swap

Tags: jquery, swap

How can I make it so when you click the 2nd time it will go back? I guess I gotta somehow find the active one but not sure.

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    $("#dsa").fadeOut()
    $("#asd").fadeIn()
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You looking for something like [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use [**`.toggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    $("#dsa, #asd").toggle(400);
});
```